# A string is immutable, so why are they not all constants?

Tags: strings, immutability

The `string` type is immutable.

We can use the `const` keyword with `strings` in high level language like .NET. My understanding of 'const' means constant (it remains the same, we can't change the value).

Are `strings` not always `constant` (IMO the term `constant` should not be applicable in the same context if the type has to be recreated each time it means for the values life time, it was constant)?

In high level languages, specifically .NET (although I'd be interested in Java too), is this due to general memory management/tracking of objects or is there another reason?

Comment: Which programming language do you use? The answer may depend on specific details of the language implementation.

Comment: Your definition of "constant" is hard to understand. Do you mean "once created it always exists"? If yes, the answer should be obvious: you'd run out of memory.

Comment: If that's not what you mean, then you're confusing objects and the variables that point to them. A "constant" in Java (and I assume .Net also) is simply a variable that can never be changed.

Comment: @parsifal, your comment reads as if the const keyword forces an object to not be disposed of. If that is true, you've answered my question.

Comment: Constant means known at compile-time. Immutable means unchangeable at runtime. You don't know at compile-time all of the strings you're going to use (and can't change - still immutable), so they can't be constants.

Comment: But @parsifal, no string *can* change! It's immutable

Comment: @DaveRook In Java, the `final` modifier on a string variable prevents the variable to be changed to point to a different string.

Comment: What exactly needs to be *constant*, what exactly can't be modified: the characters in a specific string object, or an object in a specific variable? That's two different things. In Java, strings are *immutable*, which means that when you create a string object, you *cannot* modify it... but you *can* throw it away and put another object into the same variable. The constant string ("static final String" in Java) means that you cannot even replace the object in the variable.

Comment: in C# you can think of a const as a #DEFINE in C. The compiler literally inlines the value you put in that const everywhere it's referenced (including in other assemblies that reference it)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are confusing two different things:

- *Immutable* means the object's memory contents cannot be modified. When you modify an immutable object (e.g, a `string`), the memory contents of this object are *not* modified. Instead:

  1. A *new* block of memory is allocated.
  2. The contents of the object you (tried to) modify is copied to this new block, with the part you wanted to change is changed in this new block.
  3. The pointer (i.e, the reference) is assigned to this new block.
- *Constant* means the variable cannot be modified at compile-time. Whether a `string` or an `integer` the contents of the variable (or what it points to) cannot be changed or assigned at compile time.

Comment: Thank you. I am being far to literal but this answers it very well.

Comment: If you can't modify the constant at compile-time, when do you modify it?

Comment: @parsifal If it is a `const` you *cannot* modify it. You can define it to an initial value, but you cannot assign a different value to it anywhere else, thus you cannot modify it.

Comment: @rae1n: this is not 100% correct. *Constant* means a variable cannot be modified **run-time**. It is a property of the variable which holds a string, while immutability is a property of the object itself.

Comment: @DocBrown Are you saying you can modify a Constant at compile-time?

Comment: @rae1n - This may be a terminology issue. In your reply to me you describe *runtime* modification. Compile-time modification is what happens when you change something in your text editor.

Comment: @rae1n: You might not even be able to (easily) modify a constant at compile time.  C#, for example, bakes all of your constants into the code of any referencing assemblies.  Thus, changing a constant requires a recompilation of all applications which use that constant, rather than just the library which defines it.

Comment: @parsifal: IMHO that is not correct, too. You are talking of "development time". Compile-time changes happen when you have a language like C++ and use templates or the preprocessor where macros or template arguments are replaced by the compiler during compilation stage.

Comment: @rae1n: no, I am saying that the difference between "constant" and "immutable" is not a "run time" vs. "compile time" issue. The difference lies between the variable which holds an object, and the object itself.

Comment: @parsifal I believe you might be right: I was referring to compile-time as compiling the program, at which point changing a Constant (read 're-assigning the variable to a new value after definition') would give you a compilation error.

Comment: @DocBrown You are right. It was a poor choice of words. I updated the answer to be clearer. Thanks.

Comment: @DocBrown - once you go down that route, you get into many shades of what "compile-time" means. For example, you could argue that the C++ preprocessor is not "compile time" because it runs before the actual compiler ... or alternatively, that macro replacement by your source control system *is* compile-time.

Comment: I take a much simpler approach: compile-time is anything visible to the compiler, run-time is anything that depends on the program running.

Answer (score 6):

As the comments say, you're confusing "constant" with "immutable", when they really mean two very different things.

A **constant** is a *variable* that can't be changed.  Depending on the language and the compiler, it's entirely possible for compiled code to simply replace every use of that variable with the value assigned to it, in which case it would never even be allocated a spot in memory.  Even if the compiler doesn't optimize that way, it's still allocated one spot in memory at launch (since `const` implies `static`) and stays there until exit.

An **immutable** is a *value in memory* that can't be changed (until the memory is reclaimed).  It's assigned a place in memory as needed, and it can (theoretically) be stored in multiple variables.  Assigning to a variable which is pointing at an immutable value simply creates a new immutable and alters the variable to point to that instead.  The old value stays in memory until garbage collected, which can happen even while the program is running.

Comment: +1 for explaining what constant is actually doing: inlining your variable's value everywhere it's referenced; which is an important mechanism to understand as it has even larger effects than just what's mentioned here.

Answer (score 2):

Strings can't change.  *Pointers* to strings *can* change.  The following is valid code:

```
String text = "Text";
text = text.substring(1);
```

The original "Text" object is still there, unchanged and immutable, except nothing is pointing to it anymore.  A mutable `String` would allow you to do `text.substring(1)` without having to assign it back to the `text` variable, and it would change the original object.  If you want the *variable* `text` not to change, that's when you make it a `const`.  There are valid use cases for both.

As a side note, this is a good example of a concept that's easier to understand in C++, because objects and pointers to objects have different types.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you're confusing variables and objects.

A *variable* is simply a *reference* to an *object*.

While your program is running, a *variable* can refer to multiple *objects*. Assigning something to the variable does not change the object. If there are no variables that reference an object, it becomes garbage.

A `String` is considered immutable (in Java, and I would also expect in .Net) because there is no way to change the *object*.

A *constant* is simply a variable that is not permitted to change during the life of the program. You define a constant with the `final` modifier in Java, and the `const` modifier in .Net.

However, if your "constant" variable points to a mutable object, the "constness" of the variable does not affect the mutability of the object (actually, I can't say that for sure in .Net, because I'm assuming it inherits some of the arcane rules of C++).

Comment: @Downvoter - would you care to comment? Or should I assume that you too do not know the difference between a variable and an object?

Comment: I am not the downvoter - but do you consider that not all the world is Java or C#?

Comment: @Igno - well sure, except the OP said "specifically .NET (although I'd be interested in Java" so I limited my comments to those two. That said, the separation between variable and object also applies to JavaScript, Ruby, Python, Perl, and PHP. In fact, other than C++, I can't think of another modern language that claims to be object-oriented that *doesn't* make this distinction.

Answer (score -1):

A simple demonstration of what `const` accompishes.  This is applicable to C# and similar languages.

```
string noconst = "foo";
noconst = "bar"; //noconst has changed! It was declared as "foo" but now is "bar"

const string yesconst = "foo";
yesconst = "bar"; //compiler error
```

Comment: While this demonstrates how `const` behaves, the behavior is not unique to `const`. In Java, the `final` keyword behaves similarly and in C# the `readonly` keyword does the same. The unique thing about a `const` is that it's known at compile-time.